# How to set keyboard focus to a TextBox in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to find out how to automatically set the keyboard focus to a text box in powershell.

I have a script that asks the user to select an option from a dropdown menu, then based on that selection, they have to input certain parameters. That all works fine.

For ease of use, I'd like the focus of the keyboard to shift to the input box each time a new one is shown, so the user doesn't have to keep clicking on it to enter some text.

My code so far :

```
function inputBox($parameter)
{
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = $parameter
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$paramValue=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})



$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,90)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$paramValue=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = $parameter
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

return $paramValue
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following your code, where I can find a dropdown menu, to give focus to textbox when form is shown I've done:

```
$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate(); $objTextBox.focus()})
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, too.  :-)

Comment: _Not all heroes wear capes._ The only one that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `Select` method in case `Focus()` doesn't work:

```
if($textbox.CanFocus)
{
   $textbox.Focus()
}
else
{
   $textbox.Select()
}
```

Comment: Missing a `}` in the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Works great, but I needed to make the `paramValue` variable script global (the scope inside the `Add_Click` routine is not the script scope and the `paramValue` setting is lost). Using `$Global:paramValue` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative to the answers of @CB and @Shay Levy (none of them worked for me):

```
$objForm.Add_Shown( { $objTextBox.Select() })
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Feel free to [edit] your answer to add more explanation for others. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add two additional alternative solutions to this problem.

Just move your `$objTextBox` creation code in first position above `$OKButton`.

The Code always initializes and prioritizes top to bottom. With this little change it will select your `TextBox` first.

And for a second solution add a `TabIndex` to prioritize manually.

```
$objTextBox.TabIndex = 0

$OKButton.TabIndex = 1
```

Lower numbers are prioritized and are focused first.

Answer (score -2):

The code that works with the original post and FOCUS is:

```
if ( $objTextBox.CanFocus )
{
$objTextBox.Focus()
}
else
{
$objTextBox.Select()
}
```