# how to get focus in System.Windows.Forms.TextBox powershell?

Tags: powershell, textbox

I've made a window form using powershell.

I've a textbox and i would like to focus.

How to do add a focus to TextBox and make it easier to use ?

here my code

```
...

    # TextBox
    $textbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textbox.AutoSize = $true
    $textbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,125)
    $textbox.Name = 'textbox_sw'
    $textbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(220,20)
    $textbox.Text = "Nom de la clef USB ici"
    #$textbox.Focused

...
```

Comment: this `$textbox.Focused` seems to tell IF it is focused. have you tried `.Focus()` yet? from the docs, that looks like it should _set_ the focus to the item.

Comment: yes already try with $textbox.focus() but doesn't work

Comment: thank you for the link! i was so very curious ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found it from this post [How to set keyboard focus to a TextBox in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500962/how-to-set-keyboard-focus-to-a-textbox-in-powershell)
 So it gives

```
$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate(); $textbox.Focus()}).
```

Now i've focus on my textbox