# Don’t display Cancel in PowerShell script result

Tags: powershell

I have the following PowerShell script which displays file dialog to select a txt file. If user cancels dialog then provide a multiline text box

```
function GetDetails() {
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;
  $browser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog;
  $browser.Filter = "txt (*.txt)|*.txt";
  $browser.InitialDirectory = "E:\";
  $browser.Title = "select txt file";
  $browserResult = $browser.ShowDialog();

  if($browserResult -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
    $nfoFile = $browser.FileName;

    if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($txtFile)) {
      return GetFromForm;
    }

    $txtFile = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($nfoFile, ".dac");
    $txtFile = $temp + [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($txtFile);
    $exeArgs = "-f -S `"$txtFile`" -O `"$txtFile`"";

    Start-Process $anExe -ArgumentList $exeArgs -Wait;
    $result = Get-Content $txtFile | Out-String;

    $browser.Dispose();
    return $result;
  } else {
    return GetFromForm;
  }
}


function GetFromForm(){
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;
  $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form;
  $form.Width = 800;
  $form.Height = 600;

  $txtBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox;
  $txtBox.Multiline = $true;
  $txtBox.AcceptsReturn = $true;
  $txtBox.AcceptsTab = $true;
  $txtBox.Visible = $true;
  $txtBox.Name = "txtName";
  $txtBox.Width = 760;
  $txtBox.Height = 660;

  $form.Controls.Add($txtBox);
  $form.ShowDialog();
 
  $form.Dispose();

  return $txtBox.Text;
}

$desc = GetDetails;
cls;
Write-Host $desc;
```

Here I have two issues:

1. In `Write-Host $desc`, prints also *Cancel hereiswhateverstrimg* string if user chose to cancel dialog. How to avoid that?
2. If I run script in ISE, the generated form (in second function) will be always behind ISE even I call `ShowDialog()`, I expected to behave as modal dialog. It’s normal or there is a fix for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there are a few changes that I made for efficiency and a few for functionality. Read the comments in the script for the explanations.

```
# Just add types once. There is no need to add the types in each function.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

function GetDetails() {


      $browser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog;
      $browser.Filter = "txt (*.txt)|*.txt";
      $browser.InitialDirectory = "E:\";
      $browser.Title = "select txt file";

      $browserResult = $browser.ShowDialog();

      # Combined the if statements
      if($browserResult -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK -and [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($txtFile) -ne $true) {

        $nfoFile = $browser.FileName;

        $txtFile = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($nfoFile, ".dac");
        $txtFile = $temp + [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($txtFile);
        $exeArgs = "-f -S `"$txtFile`" -O `"$txtFile`"";

        Start-Process $anExe -ArgumentList $exeArgs -Wait;

        # The Raw flag should return a string
        $result = Get-Content $txtFile -Raw;

        $browser.Dispose();

        return $result;
      }

      # No need for else since the if statement returns
      return GetFromForm;

}

function GetFromForm(){


    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form;
    $form.Text = 'Adding Arguments'
    $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(816,600)
    $form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

    # Added a button
    $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(585,523)
    $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $OKButton.Text = 'OK'
    $OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
    $form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
    $form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

    $txtBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox;
    $txtBox.Multiline = $true;
    $txtBox.AcceptsReturn = $true;
    $txtBox.AcceptsTab = $true;
    $txtBox.Visible = $true;
    $txtBox.Name = "txtName";
    $txtBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(660,500)

    $form.Controls.Add($txtBox);  

    # Needed to force it to show on top
    $form.TopMost = $true

    # Select the textbox and activate the form to make it show with focus
    $form.Add_Shown({$txtBox.Select(), $form.Activate()})

    # Finally show the form and assign the ShowDialog method to a variable (this keeps it from printing out Cancel)
    $result = $form.ShowDialog();

    # If the user hit the OK button return the text in the textbox
    if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
    {
        return $txtBox.Text
    }
}

$desc = GetDetails;
cls;
Write-Host $desc;
```

You can see reference material here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/creating-a-custom-input-box?view=powershell-6

Comment: still displays `Cancel` if user choose `Cancel` button in dialog

Comment: Did you copy my script exactly? It doesn't show cancel when I run it

Comment: Everything should be in my answer to make it work the way you want. So you should be able to just copy and paste it.

Comment: I also put comments inside of the script. So, when you copy and paste it into PowerShell, it will be extremely easy to read.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I use PowerShell 4

Comment: It still shouldn't print out Cancel as long as you assign the ShowDialog to a variable ($result = $form.ShowDialog();)

Comment: As far as I know I am not using anything that wouldn't work in PowerShell 4.

Answer (score 0):

You need to suppress output of `$form.ShowDialog()` in `GetFromForm`:

```
$form.ShowDialog()|out-null
```

Powershell will add to a return value everything that was outputted to host within a function/commandlet.

Regarding your second issue - see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500962/how-to-set-keyboard-focus-to-a-textbox-in-powershell)

And please do not use semi-colon at an end of line. This is not C# and will confuse you into thinking that the line is ended here but it's not quite true.

Comment: @SnakeEyes In your example you do not use this value at all. I'm talking about `GetFromForm` function. If you need it, then assign it to a variable, not leave the call of `ShowDialog` unassigned, otherwise it goes to stdout.

Comment: @SnakeEyes  The `Cancel` you see is not because of canceling the `OpenFile` dialog but because of closing the form with the textbox.